# Website Multilíngue com Link e Alert

Tags: javascript, html5

To desenvolvendo um site q tem 2 línguas. Como são apenas 2 línguas, pensei em usar a tag  p redirecionar o user quando ele escolher uma das duas no menu. Acham que isso pode ser uma boa prática? N imagino outra solução mais "fácil" q essa ... porém com essa coisa toda de SEO em febre, to com medo de prejudicar isso pois nunca mexi com site multilingue, é o primeiro q tento fazer

Tenho também outra questão: quero exibir um alert antes do user entrar na página, q permite escolher a língua q quer ver o site, só q ao msm tempo n acho uma boa ideia pq a mensagem q vai aparecer no alert só pode ser em 1 língua, daí imaginei a solução de buscar a língua de preferencia do user pelo navegador mas n sei fazer isso e até tentei pesquisar mas n entendi mt bem os códigos q vi ... mas enfim, agradeço quem puder me esclarecer se essas soluções são bacanas ou se devo optar por outras

Answer (score 1):

Ola, existe no proprio javascript um metodo para redirecionar caso voce deseje ou ate mesmo reconhecer a linguagem:

```
var lang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage; 
 console.log("O idioma do navegador: " + lang);
 if (lang == 'pt-BR') {
   var URLDIRECIONAR = "index.html";
   $(window.document.location).attr('href',URLDIRECIONAR);
}
else {
   var URLDIRECIONAR = "outroidioma.html";
   $(window.document.location).attr('href',URLDIRECIONAR);
}
```

recomendo ver todas as funcoes dele na documentacao: [Veja aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/language)!